# Efficiency vs Memory tradeoff

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I am creating an interactive sudoku board in c++. Whenever the user changes a value, I would like to check if the board is completed.  The board will be completed when all spaces on the board are filled. My two ideas of how to do this are:

1. Create a private data member that holds the amount of filled spaces. To check if the board is completed I will simply have to check if this value equals boardLength^2
2. Create a member function that iterates through the board and returns false when a blank space is found and true if it goes through the board without finding any blank spaces

Is this a matter of preference, or is there a more accepted/correct way to do this?

Comment: Generally, if you find yourself benchmarking code by wrapping it in a loop that executes a billion times, when in reality the code in question will execute *once* per program execution, you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a matter of preference, or is there a more accepted/correct way to do this?

There *is* an accepted and correct way of optimizing, in general:

Optimize for speed or memory footprint when you actually need to, when you identify an actual problem. Your project's unique requirements will govern what constitutes a "problem".

Otherwise, optimize your code for readability and maintainability.

In your particular case:

Chances are that no matter which algorithm you choose, your check will happen so quickly that you will not be able to measure it, and the user will *never* notice the difference between the simple solution and the "fast" solution. Any attempts to optimize this (at the cost of complexity or readability or time spent writing code) are poor trade-offs.

Use the simplest possible solution. Once finished, if there is a noticeable delay on user input, and you can confirm that it's caused by an inefficient check for board completion, consider ways to improve your algorithm.